# Genexus 17 GAM Platform could not been downloaded from

Tags: sdk, genexus, genexus-gam

I need install gamplatforms17u6.exe and don cant by show this erros:

GAM Platforms for Genexus 17 Setup Error
GAM Platform could not been downloaded from
http://dcserver.genexus.com/gam/v17u6/netpostgresql.7z

I configurated:

- Firewall Stoped
- Internet Options configurated:

  - with low security
  - Aggregated urls en sites permited

I installate 5 times and I get the same error.

Comment: How did you try to download it?
I tried using setup provided at https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/downloadcenter?data=5934 (GAM Platforms 17 Upgrade 6) and it downloaded NetPostGresql platform correctly.
Files were stored at: C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17U6\Library\GAM\Platforms\netpostgresql

Are you trying using this tool or from inside IDE?

Comment: Yes , i tried With this tool gamplatforms17u6.exe (2.37 MB) but visualize this error: 
I need install gamplatforms17u6.exe and don cant by show this erros:

GAM Platforms for Genexus 17 Setup Error GAM Platform could not been downloaded from http://dcserver.genexus.com/gam/v17u6/netpostgresql.7z

But, i tried download from Browser and I can do.

This error very difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the url http://dcserver.genexus.com/gam/v17u6/netpostgresql.7z in your browser, and you will be able to download the .7z file. Then copy it side by side with the installer file (gamplatforms17u6.exe). Run the installer again, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you suggested and it installed successfully.

Something similar happens to me when installing androidsdk17.exe, but I'll ask about it in another post.